# PHP alternative for MSSOAP.SoapClient30 in ASP.NET

Tags: php, asp.net, soap

Can somebody help me with this - I need some tips or code to connect to wsdl service, send XML request and than print response on client side. I only have primer written in ASP.NET and need PHP alternative:

```
function doXMLRequest(Xmltext)
    Set oSOAP = Server.CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient30")
    oSOAP.ClientProperty("ServerHTTPRequest") = True
    oSOAP.mssoapinit sys_xmlservice, "", "", ""
    oSOAP.ConnectorProperty("Timeout") = 600000
    myXMLResponse = oSOAP.XMLReq(XmlText)
    doXMLRequest=myXMLResponse
    set oSOAP=nothing
end function
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using SOAPClient class

```
$client = new SoapClient();
$response = $client->SomeSOAPFunction($args);
```

if you want a function where `SomeSOAPFunction` is an argument of the function :

```
function xml($fct) {
 $client = new SoapClient();
 $response = $client->{$fct}($args);
}
```

It should work

Comment: Thanks, finaly I figured out that 'XMLReq' is SOAP function. :)